# --dev option not working in Angular CLI

Tags: angular-cli-v6

Recently I upgraded to `Angular CLI 6.0.3`. My previous build script was

`"build": "ng build --output-path ../public/ui"`, which worked fine and generated files

`/ui/inline.bundle.js”.
/ui/polyfills.bundle.js”.
/ui/vendor.bundle.js”.
/ui/styles.bundle.js”.
/ui/main.bundle.js”`

I notice that after upgrade, the files been generated have different names

`main.js
polyfills.js
runtime.js
styles.js
vendor.js`

I thought that maybe the default build is `prod` so I changed my script  to 
`"build": "ng build --dev --output-path ../public/ui",`

but I get error `Unknown option: '--dev'`

What am I doing wrong? Have the generated file name changed in v6?

Comment: Yes they have changed the names.

Comment: Thanks. Happy to accept your answer if you'll like to convert you comment to an answer.

Comment: `ng build` uses `dev` by default. But you can change the build target like so:  `"build:stage": "ng build --configuration=stage"`. 
For more see https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they have changed the names of the generated bundles.

Angular cli v 1.7

**node_modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-configs/common.js**

```
output: {
        path: path.resolve(buildOptions.outputPath),
        publicPath: buildOptions.deployUrl,
        filename: `[name]${hashFormat.chunk}.bundle.js`,
        chunkFilename: `[id]${hashFormat.chunk}.chunk.js`
    }
```

Angular cli v6

**node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/common.js**

```
output: {
        path: path.resolve(root, buildOptions.outputPath),
        publicPath: buildOptions.deployUrl,
        filename: `[name]${hashFormat.chunk}.js`,
    },
```

And dev is the default mode when using `ng build` AFAIK

Comment: So what is the solution.. ?

Comment: @Rafael Run `ng build` or run `ng build --configuration=dev`